# How do games (such as Halo) scan the network to see if there are any LAN servers?

Tags: lan

In Halo 1 for PC, you could open Multiplayer and search for locally hosted servers. In many other modern games you can do this too. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely these games:

- Send [broadcasts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_%28computing%29) ("is anyone out there?") and wait for answers
- Send [multicasts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) and wait for answers (see above)
- Wait for others to shout ("Hey, I'm a server") via broadcasts / multicast

Broadcasts and multicasts are propagated in the entire local network.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, they broadcast a message over LAN. Locally hosted servers respond with an "I'm an available server!" message. Computers that are not running instances of the game server simply ignore the request.